# ZenCart admin manager assignment - trying to allow multiple admins

Tags: zen-cart

I am completely new with `ZenCart`. I have a project that is currently manageable by 1 person. That is Admin is only person to manage that shop. I have requirement to have customer executive panel. Means Admin wants to give rights to other persons to become customer executive. They would have privilege to add product, manage product, and something more like that. Only Admin would have privilege to manage executives. I mean moderators Plugin.

Is their something like that available?? Currently I m meeting up my requirements using Core PHP. integrating with sub-part of my project. I want to reduce work load of Admin, by adding up moderator panel. Please help me with proper guidance.

Comment: `Please If I ma wrong with my question instruct me or guide me instead of reporting  my reputation down.`

Comment: May i know which version of zencart you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the Admin Profiles capability which was added in since v1.5.0.

While it's possible to install an older plugin (also named Admin Profiles) onto older versions of Zen Cart, the profile features in v1.5.0 are more efficient than what the older plugin offered.